# How to add enviroment variables for AWS Amplify NextJs application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, build, environment-variables, aws-amplify

I am trying to have env variables in my nextjs frontend hosted with aws amplify.
The way you access env variables in the frontend is like so :

```
process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SOME_KEY
```

However ofcourse once built, it wouldn't work because it wasn't configured in aws amplify.
I added the variable under Enviroment Variables like so :
[image: Aws Amplify Enviroment Variables]

all great so far , however i still need to add it in my build script as per documentation like so :
[image: Aws Amplify documentation for adding env variables in build script]
and so I did but ofcourse i got an error :

[image: Error upon build time]

**So how do I add both frontend and backend env variables in my nextjs application through aws amplify ?**

Answer (score 0):

Ok after a bit of trial and error it was pretty simple and dumb from my part.
In the documentation it is assumed that  the .env file is

1. Inside a "backend" folder
2. Called .env instead of .env.local ( nextjs naming convention )
   hence why the documentation was calling to add backend/.env
   Instead all i had to do was add **1 line** :

   - echo "NEXT_PUBLIC_SOME_API_KEY=$NEXT_PUBLIC_SOME_API_KEY" >> .env.local

Notice that this is for public env variables yet im adding it in the backend build because that is how nextjs works.
So I am  assuming that this would also work for backend env variables, variables that you would put inside your nextjs api!